# Reshape long to wide adding additional columns

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID   X   Y

 1   A   A
 1   B   A
 2   C   A
 3   A   K
 3   A   A
```

All of the solutions used for repeated measurements etc. that I could find so far rely on one indicator that varies across all observations but in my case I do not have that. I basically want to summarize all of the observations in row for every `ID` in the data set.

In the end it should look like this in wide format

```
ID   X1   Y1   X2   Y2   

1    A    A    B    A 
2    C    A    NA   NA #since there is only one observation for 2 the values for X2 and Y2 should be NA
3    A    K    A    A
```

Any idea how to do this? I would prefer to use `data.table` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

melt(df, 1)[, i := paste(variable, 1:.N, sep = "_"), 
                keyby = .(ID, variable)][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ i), 
                                             .SDcols = c("ID", "value", "i")]

>    ID X_1  X_2 Y_1  Y_2
  1:  1   A    B   A    A
  2:  2   C <NA>   A <NA>
  3:  3   A    A   K    A
```

There you have:

- first you melt the data, so you have all X and Y values under one column
- Then you create a new variable that tells you if that's the first or second X or Y, grouped by ID and variable (so they're meaningful)
- Then you cast to wide that table, keeping `ID` as a column, and the new variable as column headers. You dropped the column `variable`, as you already had it coded in `i`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowid` to create a unique ID over which you can cast the data to wide.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID~rowid(ID), value.var = c('X', 'Y'))

#   ID X_1  X_2 Y_1  Y_2
#1:  1   A    B   A    A
#2:  2   C <NA>   A <NA>
#3:  3   A    A   K    A
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), X = c("A", "B", "C", 
"A", "A"), Y = c("A", "A", "A", "K", "A")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```